# Q# Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Tags: .net-core, q#

I'm creating a program in `Q#`.

> Problem

You are given two qubits in state |00⟩. Your task is to create the following state on them:
1/3–√(|00⟩+|01⟩+|10⟩)
You have to implement an operation which takes an array of 2 qubits as an input and has no output. The "output" of your solution is the state in which it left the input qubits.

> Code

```cs
namespace Solution {
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Primitive;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Canon;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Math;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Convert;

    operation Solve (qs : Qubit[]) : Unit
    {
        body
        {
            Ry(ArcCos(Sqrt(2.0/3.0))*2.0,qs[0]);
            (ControlledOnInt(0,H))([qs[0]],qs[1]);
        }
    }    
}
```

But when I run it show me the following error.

> Error

```
CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point 

[C:\Users\Pawar\Desktop\HK\codeforces\Q#\Solution\Solution.csproj]
```

So I tried to put `EntryPoint()` before the method declaration . Which shows me different error as

> error QS6231: Invalid entry point. Values of type Qubit may not be used as arguments or return values to entry points. [C:\Users\Pawar\Desktop\HK\codeforces\Q#\Solution\Solution.csproj]

Please help me how to run it properly ? 
thanks ✌️

Comment: The error is pretty clear. In all languages you need to provide one entry point. The error explains what you need to do too - create a static `Main` method

Comment: I know it requiring me for Main method. but even the Q# hello program created by VSCODE Q# extension has not the Main method. It only has the  `operation HelloQ()`

Comment: Plus the code I have posted runs perfectly on the codeforces. see this https://codeforces.com/contest/1116/submission/83528419

Comment: Which doesn't mean anything. A site running scripts is nothing like an application that needs to be compiled and run. You have a `csproj` project which means you have a *C#* program. That C# program needs a `Main` method

Comment: .csproj file is actually a xml file that stores some of the attributes like Project SDK , PropertyGroup,OutputType,TargetFramework

Comment: If you just want it to compile as a library without an entry point, you can remove `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>` from your .csproj file. That should succeed (once you also remove the @EntryPoint from your code). But if you want to run it as an executable, you would need to actually change the signature of your @EntryPoint operation, as pointed out in the error message. Specifically, instead of having `Qubit[]` as an argument, you'd probably just want to allocate those qubits inside your operation (e.g. via `using (qs = Qubit[2]) { ... }`).

Comment: If OutputType is removed then it say ` Ensure you have a runnable project type and ensure 'dotnet run' supports this project.
A runnable project should target a runnable TFM (for instance, netcoreapp2.0) and have OutputType 'Exe'.
The current OutputType is 'Library' `

Comment: Right, you can only run projects if they are executables. So in order to run it, you will need an EntryPoint. There's an example here of an EntryPoint that calls other operations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/quickstarts/qrng?tabs=tabid-qsharp#creating-a-complete-random-number-generator

Comment: Also here's a nice blog post discussing Q# EntryPoint operations in more detail: https://qsharp.community/blog/qsharp-entrypoint/

Comment: @AashishPawar csproj is a C# project file. Threre's no if or but about it. Yes, it's XML, yes, it contains project types, elements like OutputType, TargetFramework inside PropertyGroup elements, PackageReference types etc. That project needs a `Main`. There's no if or but about that either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to run a Q# program as an executable, you need to have an `@EntryPoint()` operation defined. You can read more in this excellent blog post: https://qsharp.community/blog/qsharp-entrypoint/.

Specifically, in your case, the error message indicates that `Qubit[]` is not a valid parameter to the main entry point of your program. Which makes sense, because it doesn't make sense to pass an array of qubits when executing a program from the command line. And also, your operation doesn't print anything or return any results, so you won't be able to see what it's doing.

You should probably create an `@EntryPoint()` wrapper operation that invokes your existing operation with the appropriate parameters, maybe prints some diagnostics, and then returns some result. In your case, you could perhaps do something like this (note the additional namespaces you need to open):

```
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Diagnostics;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Measurement;

    @EntryPoint()
    operation SolveForTwoQubits() : Result[]
    {
        using (qubits = Qubit[2])
        {
            Solve(qubits);                 // invoke your existing Solve operation
            DumpMachine();                 // outputs the state of your qubits
            let results = MultiM(qubits);  // measure the qubits
            ResetAll(qubits);              // reset the qubits to the initial state
            return results;                // return the measured results
        }
    }
```

This will give some output that looks like:

```
# wave function for qubits with ids (least to most significant): 0;1
∣0❭:     0.577350 +  0.000000 i  ==     *******              [ 0.333333 ]     --- [  0.00000 rad ]
∣1❭:     0.577350 +  0.000000 i  ==     *******              [ 0.333333 ]     --- [  0.00000 rad ]
∣2❭:     0.577350 +  0.000000 i  ==     *******              [ 0.333333 ]     --- [  0.00000 rad ]
∣3❭:     0.000000 +  0.000000 i  ==                          [ 0.000000 ]
[Zero,One]
```

Comment: I have post codeforces submission link above the Question has given the exact format to use. I want to run that code on using Q# SDK on my local machine.

Comment: You'll need to define a wrapper operation that will allocate qubits and pass them to the Solve operation. On Codeforces, the testing harness does it for you, but if you're creating your own project, you need to take care of that.

Comment: see here codeforces.com/contest/1116/submission/83528419 I need to use template as defined in the contest

Comment: @AashishPawar most likely you misunderstood the contest rules. Rules can't change how a language and its compiler work, and unless you specify an `@EntryPoint` you won't be able to execute your program. That site accepts incomplete *scripts* and passes them to a wrapper as Mariia explained. An executable program is completely different